# When I use jquery's .hide feature to toggle some div's, the divs overlap following divs (only in ie8)

Tags: jquery, select, show-hide

I am using jquery to hide and show some divs, based on select box choices. When I change the value of the select box, the action that should happen does, but the div that is shown is underneath the next div (the div's arent being "pushed" down).

this is the jquery code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#alldates').hide();
$('#dateselect').hide();
$('#dateselectchoices').change(function(){
$('#' + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});
$('#dateselectchoices').change();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#nocountyselect').hide();
$('#countyselect').hide();
$('#regionselect').hide();
$('#countyselectchoices').change(function(){
$('#' + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});
$('#countyselectchoices').change();
});
</script>
```

And the ensuing html:

```
<div class="tbl_container">
<span class="tbl_left">Registered Date Range:</span>
<span class="tbl_right"><select id='dateselectchoices' name='$rangename'><option value='alldates'>All Dates</option>
<option value='dateselect'>Specify Date Range</option>
</select>

<div id='boxes'>
<div id='alldates'></div>
<div id='dateselect'><span style='width:80px; display:inline-block;'>Start Date: </span><span style='display:inline-block;'>
<input type='text' class='input-medium' name='rangestart' id='rangestart' />&nbsp;<a href='#' onClick=\"cal.select(document.getElementById('rangestart'),'startanchor','yyyy-MM-dd'); return false;\" name='startanchor' id='startanchor'>
<img src='http://www.ampltek.net/marn/calendar.jpg' border='0' /></a></span><br/>
<span style='width:80px; display:inline-block;'>End Date: </span><span style='display:inline-block;'>
<input type='text' class='input-medium' name='rangeend' id='rangeend' />&nbsp;<a href='#' onClick=\"cal.select(document.getElementById('rangeend'),'endanchor','yyyy-MM-dd'); return false;\" name='endanchor' id='endanchor'>
<img src='http://www.ampltek.net/marn/calendar.jpg' border='0' /></a></span></div>
</div>
</span>
</div>

<div class="tbl_container">
<span class="tbl_left">County/Region:</span>
<span class="tbl_right"><select id='countyselectchoices' name='countyselectchoices'>
<option value='nocountyselect' selected='selected'>Any</option>
<option value='countyselect'>County</option>
<option value='regionselect'>Region</option>
</select>
<div id='boxes2' style='display:inline-block; -moz-inline-stack; zoom: 1; *display: inline;'>
<div id='nocountyselect'></div><div id='countyselect'><?php countySelect(countychoice); ?></div><div id='regionselect'><?php regionSelect(regionchoice); ?></div>
</div></span>
</div>
```

The second one of these select boxes doesn't create an option, since the box it shows displays in-line with it.  Any thoughts?  Everything works fine in Firefox 3/Chrome...

Comment: Is that not how you expect it to behave? http://jsfiddle.net/aabxe/ it's exactly your code (replacing the php parts with plain text) and it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with a webpage recently.
Ive heard IE8 is not compatible with jquery, although this seems odd.

I solved my problem by putting this line in the header tags.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```